# How can I refer to AutoCAD block

Tags: vba, excel, autocad, autocad-plugin

I having autocad project where is 1 dynamic block which I'm trying to change from excel. 
Here is vba script which I'm using to change block:

```
Dim dybprop As Variant, i As Integer
Dim bobj As AcadEntity

For Each bobj In ACADApp.ModelSpace
    If bobj.ObjectName = "AcDbBlockReference" Then
        If bobj.IsDynamicBlock Then
            If bobj.EffectiveName = "AdjBlock" Then
                dybprop = bobj.GetDynamicBlockProperties
                For i = LBound(dybprop) To UBound(dybprop)
                    If dybprop(i).PropertyName = "Distance1" Then
                        dybprop(i).Value = 50.75
                        Acad.Application.Update
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next

End With
```

When I'm running it in AutoCAD VBA it works excellent. Than I'm creating Excel VBA project and copying this code. Before running it I creating connection to existing AutoCad project like this:

```
  On Error Resume Next

   Dim ACADApp As AcadApplication
   Dim a As Object

   Set a = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")

   If a Is Nothing Then
      Set a = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")

      If a Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "AutoCAD must be running before performing this action.", vbCritical
         Exit Sub
      End If
   End If

   Set ACADApp = a

   Set ACADApp.ActiveDocument = ACADApp.Documents.Open("c:\KIRILL\Programming\Drawing1_VBATest.dwg")
```

When I'm running it from Excel VBA - AutoCAD project appears but nothing change. Honestly I don't have any idea why in Excel VBA it doesn't works while in AutoCAD it work. May be somebody had this problem before? Thanks in advance.

P.S. Full Excel VBA code:

```
Sub Button9_Click()

  On Error Resume Next

   Dim ACADApp As AcadApplication
   Dim a As Object

   Set a = GetObject(, "AutoCAD.Application")

   If a Is Nothing Then
      Set a = CreateObject("AutoCAD.Application")

      If a Is Nothing Then
         MsgBox "AutoCAD must be running before performing this action.", vbCritical
         Exit Sub
      End If
   End If

   Set ACADApp = a

   Set ACADApp.ActiveDocument = ACADApp.Documents.Open("c:\KIRILL\Programming\Drawing1_VBATest.dwg")

Dim dybprop As Variant, i As Integer
Dim bobj As AcadEntity

For Each bobj In ACADApp.ModelSpace
    If bobj.ObjectName = "AcDbBlockReference" Then
        If bobj.IsDynamicBlock Then
            If bobj.EffectiveName = "AdjBlock" Then
                dybprop = bobj.GetDynamicBlockProperties
                For i = LBound(dybprop) To UBound(dybprop)
                    If dybprop(i).PropertyName = "Distance1" Then
                        dybprop(i).Value = 50.75
                        Acad.Application.Update
                    End If
                Next i
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next



End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried any **basic debugging**? Adding breakpoints inside loops and inspecting objects?  Even basic `Debug.Print` statements to determine how far into your loops the code is getting into? Start by changing `On Error Resume Next` to `On Error Goto 0`

Comment: this line... `Acad.Application.Update` - why are you not using your `ACADApp` object?

Comment: Can’t you just add a reference to the Autocad Library and avoid the need for the GetObject calls? And as per comments, use the debugger and follow it step by step.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the reference library?

You can go to:

> Tools->References

And add:

> [**AutoCAD 20xx Type Library**]